# How to send Set-Cookie header Angular2, Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, session-cookies

I'm trying to set session id by using Set-Cookie header. 
Angular 2 code:

```js
let headers = new Headers(); //Headers
headers.append('Set-Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=' + sha1(APP_CONFIG.localHost) + ';  path=/'); //Setting my own cookie id 
let options = new RequestOptions({ //Set request options
       headers: headers,
       withCredentials: true
});
    
this.http.get(url, options);
```

So I want to set my own cookie id on server but it isn't in headers.
[image]
How to do this right?

At PHP server I use this code:

```
$this->app->headers
                    ->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100') //Разрешаем запросы к API со всех доменов
                    ->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS') 
                    ->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Set-Cookie, Content-type') 
                    ->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
                    ->addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: its a cors issue.. wont really matter in a device..At the server side. where you set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, change `*` to `http://localhost:8100` you cant allow `*` when you have `withCredentials` as true

Comment: I added this header to response. But to Set-Cookie header present. What it can be?

Comment: can i use cookies for authenticated web api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I need to use not Set-Cookie header. I need to use Cookie header. But the problem is that my Google Chrome browser is refuse it. The solution is to query server with this parameter that contains session_id. And at server side set it.